# Which USB wireless adapters are supported by Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers

I bought a netgear n150 wn1100 usb wireless adapter and it seems like I have to go through ten pages of obscure documentation just to get it to work. Does anyone know of a plug and play usb wireless adapter that plays well with ubuntu? I would like to return the one that I have and buy something that makes this a little bit more simple.

Comment: could you run lsusb with it plugged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most wireless adaptors use the [linux wireless drivers](http://linuxwireless.org/) and there's a comprehensive list of wireless chipsets supported by [the drivers](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers) and their level of support. Sadly most drivers don't come with information on what chipsets they use - you can find a [list here that should be of use](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Devices/USB) in selecting a specific device.

Answer (score 0):

[Various Realtek chipsets](http://wiki.debian.org/rtl818x) are supported in the Linux kernel (RTL8180L, RTL8187L,  RTL8187SE), so a USB wireless adaptor that uses one of these chipsets should work.

Realtek chipset are used by many different manufacturers, including Netgear.  Most Intel chipsets are probably well supported as well.